# scrollTop() if/else switchClass() animation for shrinking nav bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

I use the jQUery UI method `switchClass()` because I want to have control over the animation duration. One thing I am confused by is the identifying classes in the switchClass() methods.  Do I use the '.' before one class but not for the other? Below is my code. As it is, it's not working.  Is there a more elegant solution to this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on("scroll touchmove", function () {
        var x = $(document).scrollTop();
        if( x > 0 ) {
         $('.header').switchClass('header', '.header.tiny', 500);
         $('.logo').switchClass('logo', '.logo.tiny', 500);
        } else {
         $('.logo.tiny').switchClass('tiny', '.logo', 500);
         $('.header.tiny').switchClass('tiny', '.header', 500);
       };
      });
    });
```

https://jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the '.' see:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function () {
    var x = $(document).scrollTop();
    if( x > 0 ) {
     $('div.header').switchClass('header', 'tiny', 500);
     $('div.logo').switchClass('logo', 'tiny', 500);
    } else {
     $('div.logo div.tiny').switchClass('tiny', 'logo', 500);
     $('div.header div.tiny').switchClass('tiny', 'header', 500);
   };
  });
});
```

And try to define your classes with objects e.g: div.header